# Is it legal to bribe an employee of a fully private company?

Tags: united-states, bribery

Let's say I go into Starbucks and slip an extra dollar to the barrista so that he gives me a slice of cake for free (just a small example). Is this legal according to criminal law?

I know it's illegal to bribe state employees, but I never understood how the law applies to 100% private companies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the USA, there is no federal law that expressly prohibits bribes in a commercial context (*"commercial bribing"*), but there are laws in many states - so it depends on the state. Most states do have laws about it.

---

For example, the law in the state of New York is quite strict. What you describe would qualify as "commercial bribing in the second degree". You would be liable under § 180.00:

> A person is guilty of commercial bribing in the second degree when he
>   confers, or offers or agrees to confer, any benefit upon any employee,
>   agent or fiduciary without the consent of the latter's employer or
>   principal, with intent to influence his conduct in relation to his
>   employer's or principal's affairs.
>
> Commercial bribing in the second degree is a class A misdemeanor.

*[New York Penal Law § 180.00 - Commercial bribing in the second degree](http://codes.findlaw.com/ny/penal-law/pen-sect-180-00.html)*

The employee receiving the bribe would also be liable, under [§ 180.05 - Commercial bribe receiving in the second degree](http://codes.findlaw.com/ny/penal-law/pen-sect-180-05.html):

> An employee, agent or fiduciary is guilty of commercial bribe
>   receiving in the second degree when, without the consent of his
>   employer or principal, he solicits, accepts or agrees to accept any
>   benefit from another person upon an agreement or understanding that
>   such benefit will influence his conduct in relation to his employer's
>   or principal's affairs.
>
> Commercial bribe receiving in the second degree is a class A
>   misdemeanor.

Comment: Also, a contract based on bribery is void at common law

Comment: Even if your state doesn't have laws like that, I imagine the employer could still sue you for tortious interference, but IANAL.

Comment: @flarn2006: Yes, that is true (though to nitpick, the question was explicitly about criminal responsibility).